# Fragments of old tables left behind after DROP SCHEMA

Tags: mysql

I'm attempting to drop and recreate a MySQL schema but it appears that fragments of the old schema reappear when I do this.

I have a script to create the new schema thus...

```
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL';

DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS `scunthorpe` ;

CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `scunthorpe` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 ;
USE `scunthorpe` ;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `location` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `location` (
      `id_location` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
      `location` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id_location`) )
    ENGINE = InnoDB
    DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `strand` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `strand` (
    `id_location` INT NOT NULL ,
    `id_strand` INT NOT NULL ,
    `notes` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_location`, `id_strand`) ,
  INDEX `strand_location_fkey` (`id_location` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `strand_location_fkey`
  FOREIGN KEY (`id_location` )
      REFERENCES `location` (`id_location` )
      ON DELETE CASCADE
      ON UPDATE CASCADE)
  ENGINE = InnoDB
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;
```

This produces the error:

```
ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table '.\scunthorpe\strand.frm' (errno: 150)
```

Perusing the `show innodb status` reveals the following:-

```
111021 10:46:17 Error in foreign key constraint of table scunthorpe/straightenin
g_temperature:
there is no index in referenced table which would contain
the columns as the first columns, or the data types in the
referenced table do not match to the ones in table. Constraint:
,
  CONSTRAINT straightening_to_strand_fkey FOREIGN KEY (id_location, id_sequence,
 id_strand) REFERENCES strand (id_location, id_sequence, id_strand)
```

Now there was, at about the time of the Norman conquest, such a table in the schema. But the drop schema should get rid of it, no? So does anyone know why this is reappearing and what I should do about it?

**Edit 1**

As suggested by devart, I tried `REPAIR TABLE` but this is apparently not supported for InnoDB. I inspected the files and found the schema directory was deleted after the `DROP SCHEMA` statement, and recreated on `CREATE SCHEMA`, as one would expect. Agent Ransack revealed the offending string `straightening_to_strand_fkey` was present in a file called `ibdata1`, whatever that is.

Comment: Looks like the `ENGINE = InnoDB` is ignored. `.frm` indicates a MyISAM table storage if I'm not mistaken. You verify if InnoDB is really available by using `show engine innodb status`

Comment: @a_horse, thank you. I tried the `show engine...` command, and the reponse appears to me to show that InnoDB is available (recent timestamps and so forth).

Comment: Did you modify these tables before the schema re-creation? Were there any errors?

Comment: @Devart, almost certainly; this is a development database, and there were for sure many errors and much swearing, but this was several months ago and I can't remember the details or what it ended up like, so I decided to drop the schema and start again.

Comment: What is the table `straightening_temperature`?

Comment: @Devart, sorry, losing the plot here. I can't find any definition of this table in any schema in the database, and I'm starting to doubt it ever really existed. There's no such table in any of the create scripts in use, and no trace of it anywhere in the database (in any schema) now.

Comment: Can you try to drop this table? - DROP TABLE scunthorpe.straightening_temperature;

Comment: @Devart, thank you for the suggestion. Yesterday, I destroyed and recreated the database, so now the new schema is bowling along merrily. I should have put a comment in to say so, as doing that can't really be described as a "solution", so ought not to be an answer. Thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this recommendations will help to resolve the problem:

- run REPAIR TABLE
- delete specified files in the data directory - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table-problems.html.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've edited the question to show the (unsuccessful) results.